# Adding Microsoft Graph to existing Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-5, query-string, microsoft-graph-sdks

I got an API on .NET 5, made with Entity Framework Core.

The query-URLs with methods are something like `GET https://api.mydomain.ch/v1/applicationusers`

This would retrieve all application users (which makes sense).

In C# this looks:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<ApplicationUser>> Get()
{
    return Ok(await _applicationUserRepository.GetAll());
}
```

Now a client that consumes my API wants to request: `GET https://api.mydomain.ch/v1/applicationusers?$filter=startswith(givenName,'Peter')`

I have seen this matches the Microsoft Graph API and its query parameters. And my client also wants to use the other implementations for this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters)

I couldn't find any implementation example that works with Entity Framework Core. Is it possible to implement this with an easy way, and not to make big modifications on the database?

Do I need to implement the functions completely on my own? Or is there support from Microsoft between those query parameter functions and Entity Framework Core?

Comment: Well, getting your user information from MS Graph instead of your database is going to be a **fundamental** change .... basically, your database won't be used anymore at all, for anything user related - all the information will come from the MS Graph (and whatever user data store you have behind that - Azure Active Directory for instance). ..... not sure if that's an "easy way" to implement this .....

Comment: @marc_s so you think (or probably you know) there is no easy way (or any way at all) to just use graph query parameters and "parse" them to combine them with ef core database?

Comment: Well, if you "just" want the nifty features (like being able to sort and filter) as MS Graph offers - you could always check out how to make your own service (on `api.mydomain.ch`) support the **OData** protocol - that's the "magic" that makes these things possible.

Comment: @marc_s ah this sounds like an idea... bit effort, but probably still saves more time than implementing those query parameters in old way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay the answer is quite simple and it's not the Microsoft Graph that needs to be implemented, but simply `OData`.

For .NET 5 it's not well documented, since the NuGet for this .NET-version is still in RC-state (pre-release).

To implement OData, we need to add `Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData` in nuget packages. *My answer is written with state from `8.0.0-rc`. For v7.x the calls look bit different but are better documented.*

What we need to do is:

Add OData in `StartUp.ConfigureServices`:

```cs
ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new(new DefaultAssemblyResolver());
builder.EntitySet<ApplicationUser>("ApplicationUser");
IEdmModel model =  builder.GetEdmModel();

services.AddOData(opt =>
{
    opt
        .AddModel("api/v1", model)
        .Select()
        .Expand()
        .OrderBy()
        .Filter()
        .Count();
});
```

with `.Select().Expand().OrderBy().Filter().Count()` you add the api-query-parameters for $select, $expand,...

My `UseEndpoints` call in `Configure()` looks this way:

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
```

Make sure, the controller inherit from `ODataApiController`.
An action looks like this:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[EnableQuery]
public async Task<ActionResult<ApplicationUser>> Get()
{
    return Ok(await _applicationUserRepository.GetAll());
}
```

This would not execute the expected query. We need to return the `IQueryable<T>` to make this work, so we don't query for all records:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<ApplicationUser> Get()
{
    return _applicationUserRepository.GetAll();
}
```